# React Slick does not have default horizontal behaviour as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the library react-slick to get these demos to work on my system. As expected react slick should get arrows and horizontal behaviour but I don't see that happening even after using the same code.

Here is the codepen for this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-napier-4jg7p

Here is the library I am trying to use:
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick 
and the demo they have on codepen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ppwkk5l6xx

I used this last codepen demo but it didn't work as expected on my system and I didn't see any arrows in the carousel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add slick.min.css and slick-theme.min.css as external resource.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css

That will solve your problem immediately.

Enjoy!